# I keep get this error with str.Split: Assets\Scripts\store.cs(15,26): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

Tags: unity, c#

I keep getting this error:

Assets\Scripts\store.cs(15,26): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

When I try this:

```
public static string[] toArray(string str) {     
        return str.Split(" , ");
}
```

I know other questions have answered this but they haven't worked. :(
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The method require a `char` not `string`

```
public static string[] toArray(string str) {     
        return str.Split(',');
}
```

Try use code editor recommended by Unity like [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). It show error right away and how to fix them.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This basically saved my app!